# Force Haswell CPU to fixed frequency

Tags: linux, x86, cpu-frequency

For stability of benchmarks I wish to run the E5-2680 v3 2.5 GHz CPUs in my Dell R430 test servers running Fedora 23 at their nominal frequency - no more, no less.

I've disabled the `intel_pstate` driver, and `/proc/cpuinfo` appears to indicate that they're running at the requested speed, with all cores showing ~2500 MHz.

However : the `cpufreq` program shows that the frequencies are not fixed, e.g. on a server with one core running a heavy load:

```
# cpupower monitor -m Mperf
    |Mperf               
CPU | C0   | Cx   | Freq 
   0|  3.48| 96.52|  1198
   1|  7.28| 92.72|  1198
   2|  4.88| 95.12|  1198
   3|  3.76| 96.24|  1198
   4|  3.53| 96.47|  1198
   5|  7.17| 92.83|  1198
   6|  4.18| 95.82|  1198
   7|  8.75| 91.25|  1198
   8|  8.51| 91.49|  1198
   9|  6.41| 93.59|  1198
  10| 99.98|  0.02|  2896
  11|  7.33| 92.67|  1198
```

So, apparently that one core is running above the nominal rate, and the other 11 cores are idling.

It's possible that `cpupower` is giving me bad information, but if not it's essential for my benchmarks that the CPU cores do run at a consistent speed.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to fix the speed as I require?

Answer (score 2):

I've subsequently discovered that this was because the BIOS System Profile setting was set to the default "SysDbpm" (BIOS controlled Speedstep) instead of "OsDbpm" (O/S controlled).

With the BIOS set appropriately and rebooted the `acpi-cpufreq` driver regained proper control over the CPU frequency.

Comment: oddly, it seems that even with this setting the "min frequency" is not being adhered to, and idle cores still drop below 2500 MHz.